# What is the importance of the % symbol as used inside a SAS macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Please consider this sample SAS macro code:

```
%MACRO reports;
   %IF &SYSDAY = Monday %THEN %DO;
   %END;
%MEND reports;
```

Does every single word inside the macro need to be prefixed with a `%`? What exactly does the `%` sign mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%` is a [macro trigger](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/a001071824.htm), along with `&`.  It identifies the next symbol(s) as part of a macro language element.  This might be a macro call (`%reports();`), a macro statement (`%if`), a macro comment (`%*`), or other macro language elements.

Understanding how the SAS macro language works is pretty important to understanding the difference here.  `%IF` for example is instructing the SAS macro processor to do something.  `IF` is regular SAS code that will be put into the SAS data step (or whatever).  Spend some time understanding what the macro language is doing - what the point of it is entirely - to fully understand that.

And, as with many things in SAS, [Ian Whitlock can explain it better than I can.](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/CC09.Whitlock.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The `%` symbol indicates that it is macro logic, no datastep logic.

Macro logic is executed before compilation, just like pre-compiler logic in C++. Fro instance

```
%MACRO  reports ;
data lastWorkingDayData;
    set allData;
    %IF   &SYSDAY = Monday 
    %THEN %DO ;  
        if transactionDate ge "&SYSDATE."d -3 then output;
    %END ;
    %ELSE %DO ;  
        if transactionDate ge "&SYSDATE."d -1 then output;
    %END ;
RUN  ;
/* your printing logic comes here */
%MEND   reports ;
%reports;
```

will, if you run it today be converted before it is even compiled to

```
data lastWorkingDayData;
    set allData;
        if transactionDate ge "&SYSDATE."d -3 then output;
RUN  ;
/* your printing logic comes here */
```

before it is even compiled. To understand it better, start your code with `option mprint;` and inspect your log

Comment: Because this if statement must not determine which SAS code is to be compiled (is not to be executed before compilation) but must determine for which observations (=rows) the `output;` statement should be executed after compilation.